# How to figure out what exception to catch in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception, jruby

I was given some code that keeps getting an exception raised from a jRuby library. The code only handles certain exceptions but it misses the one I keep getting.

Is there a way I can figure out how to capture that specific exception without digging into the Library code?

Comment: "[Alternative to 'rescue Exception'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18596924/128421)" is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point where your exception causes the program to exit, you should be *shown* the type of exception being raised.

For example, I've bolded the type of exception as reported by IRB in the following example:

> irb(main):001:0> def do_it(a,b); end; do_it(3,4,5)
>   **ArgumentError**: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
>       from (irb):1:in `do_it'
>       from (irb):1
>       from /Users/meagar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `'

Based on this, I would know I needed to handle `ArgumentError`.

Failing that, you can catch *all* exceptions, use a debugger in your exception handler to inspect the caught exception and figure out its type, and then replace the catch-all with the correct exception type.

Comment: As said, it's important to stress and re-stress that we want to catch the specific exception, not the generic `Exception`. All sorts of evil can break loose if Exception or the bare `rescue` is used.

Comment: Although [Pokémon Exception Handling](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/319088/is-indiscriminately-catching-exceptions-pokemon-exception-handling-ever-accept) is generally frowned upon, it's a good way to know what type of exception that code is generating and write a response to it. `rescue => e` and then inspect `e.class` to know what's going on.

Comment: If it wasn't obvious, I'm not suggesting that a catch-all **remain in the code**, I'm suggesting using it only to determine via debugger the correct type of exception to handle, and then *replacing* the catch-all with the correct type.

Comment: @meagar Just adding clarification there as your example only works in `irb`.

Comment: @tadman The exception is shown to you regardless of how you invoke the program, though the format is different. `echo 'raise "no"' > test.rb; ruby test.rb` => `test.rb:1:in \`<main>': no (RuntimeError)`

Comment: This presumes it isn't caught/consumed by something farther up the stack, which sometimes it is inside a bigger framework like Rails.

Comment: @tadman Yes, and regardless of whether Rails catches the exception or not, "you should be shown the type of exception being raised.".